# Ionic Compiling Your App Does Not Compile

Tags: ionic-framework

I tried compiling a basic Tabs template with Angular and React with Github on Windows, and the compiler just endlessly tells me to "hang tight."

Comment: Could you post more details about your issue ? For example full output of the build command

Comment: After 5-6 hours, it finally compiled.